# Problem with nicematrix environnement

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow, nicematrix

I just came to receive a solution from a member in S of a table. The solution worked very well and I really thank him for what he shared with me to overcome this issue. However, I have seen an expected lines in the pdf viewer which are illustrated in the following image.

[image]

You can check my code here :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{changepage,threeparttable}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr#1-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}}   
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{C{0.15\linewidth}C{0.275\linewidth}C{0.125\linewidth} C{0.45\linewidth}}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=6pt ]   
      \RowStyle{\bfseries} Eléments    & Ration usuel                              & Valeur    & Notations \\
    Hauteur             & $ \dfrac{L}{25} < h < \dfrac{L}{20} $                 & \SI{230}{cm}  
    & \Block{13-1}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height =150pt]{example-image}}  \\
    Largeur             & B                                                     & \SI{900}{cm}  &   \\
    C                   & $\dfrac{B}{4}$                                        & \SI{225}{cm}  &   \\
    D                   & $B - 2C $                                             & \SI{450}{cm}  &   \\
    $e_{ 1}$            & $ e_{1} \geqslant 16 $ à \SI{18}{cm}                  & \SI{20}{cm}   &   \\
    $e_{2}$             & $\dfrac{C}{8} \leqslant e_{2} \leqslant \dfrac{C}{7}$ & \SI{35}{cm}   &   \\
    $e_{ 3}$            & $ e_{3} > e_{2}$ -\SI{10}{cm} et  $e_{3} > 1.5 e_{4}$ & \SI{45}{cm}   &   \\
    $e_{4}$             & $\dfrac{D}{30}\leqslant e_{4} \leqslant \dfrac{D}{25}$ & \SI{25}{cm}  &   \\
    Inclinaison         & $\qty{10}{\percent} \leqslant \beta \leqslant \qty{30}{\percent} $ & \qty{23}{\percent}   &   \\
    $E_{a}$             & $E_{a} \geqslant 0.26 + \dfrac{L}{500} $              & \SI{50}{cm}   &   \\
    $ E_{b} $           & $ E_{p} \geqslant (\SI{18}{cm}, 3\phi, \dfrac{e_{a}}{3})$  & \SI{35}{cm}  &   \\
    Gousset supérieur   & $ \ang{30} < \alpha< \ang{45}$                        & \qty{30}{\degree} &   \\
    Gousset inférieur   & $ \ang{30} < \alpha < \ang{45} $                      & \ang{30}          &   \\
\end{NiceTabular}
    \captionof{table}{Les dimensions des différentes composantes des voussoirs. }

\end{document}
```

Please if you find any solution to this problem, let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Delete `showframe` from `geometry` options. It serves only to show page layout and should not be used in real (final) document.

Comment: These lines are due to the `showframe` option that you put when you load the `geometry` package.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is solved by coments.